# How to serialize to char* using Google Protocol Buffers?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to serialize my protocol buffer to a char*. Is this possible? I know one can serialize to file as per:

```
fstream output("/home/eamorr/test.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
if (!address_book.SerializeToOstream(&output)) {
  cerr << "Failed to write address book." << endl;
  return -1;
}
```

But I'd like to serialize to a C-style char* for transmission across a network.

How to do this? Please bear in mind that I'm very new to C++.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That's easy:

```
size_t size = address_book.ByteSizeLong(); 
void *buffer = malloc(size);
address_book.SerializeToArray(buffer, size);
```

Check [documentation of MessageLite class](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite.html) also, it's parent class of Message and it contains useful methods.

Comment: How do I access this SerializeToArray function? Thanks,

Comment: int size = address_book.ByteSize(); void *buffer = malloc(size); address_book.SerializeToArray(buffer, size);

Comment: Hi Evgen, has SerializeToArray been deprecated or something? I'm using the latest version of protocol buffers

Comment: no, it's not deprecated. if address_book is a pointer to subclass of Message you should call it with arrow: `address_book->SerializeToArray(buffer, size);`

Comment: Tried arrow notation. Something must be up here. I checked my generated protobuf header file and the only serialization functions are SerializeWithCachedSizes and SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your class is subclass of Message or MessageLite, this method defined in MessageLite and it's should work without issues. Try to find your mistake. ;)

Comment: Yeah, got it working now. It's just it wasn't showing up in Eclipse autocomplete.

Comment: Looks like [size_t ByteSizeLong()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.ByteSizeLong.details) is the new correct way to get the size.

Comment: @teeks99 It's confusing a bit, because SerializeToArray still receives int.

Answer (score 12):

You can serailze the output to a `ostringstream` and use `stream.str()` to get the string and then access the c-string with `string.c_str()`.

```
std::ostringstream stream;
address_book.SerializeToOstream(&stream);

string text = stream.str();
char* ctext = text.c_str();
```

Don't forget to include `sstream` for `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: One more thing - I don't have a SerializeToOstream function available - just a SerializeWithCachedSizes(...) and SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(...) ;(

Comment: According to Google's protobuf docs, the protobuf format is binary, and therefore could contain null bytes. I have run across occasions where calling c_str() on the output of Protobuf serialization results in a truncated C string, because the null bytes get written to the provided buffer, and further use of that buffer with normal C-style functions interprets it as ending with a null terminator. 

I wouldn't recommend using this method at all - frankly, I don't believe it's ever safe to serialize protobufs to C-style strings, and that's probably why Google doesn't provide this option.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ByteSizeLong()` to get the number of bytes the message will occupy and then `SerializeToArray()` to populate an array with the encoded message.

Answer (score 5):

Solution with a smart pointer for the array:

```
size_t size = address_book.ByteSizeLong();
std::unique_ptr<char[]> serialized(new char[size]);
address_book.SerializeToArray(&serialized[0], static_cast<int>(size));
```

Answer (score 1):

Still one more line of code to take care of the fact that the serialized data can contain zero's.

```
std::ostringstream stream;
address_book.SerializeToOstream(&stream);

string text = stream.str();
char* ctext = text.c_str();    // ptr to serialized data buffer
//  strlen(ctext) would wrongly stop at the 1st 0 it encounters.
int   data_len = text.size();  // length of serialized data
```